# FxCop custom rule to check namespace

Tags: c#, fxcop, fxcop-customrules

I am trying to write a custom rule in FxCop to validate if my namespace starts with a particular word. I have tried something like below:

```
    public override ProblemCollection Check(string namespaceName, TypeNodeCollection types)
    {
        if (namespaceName == null)
        {
            return this.Problems;
        }

        if (!namespaceName.StartsWith("FujiXerox.ApeosWare.", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            this.Problems.Add(new Problem(this.GetNamedResolution("NamespaceResolution", namespaceName)));
        }

        return this.Problems;
    }
```

But it is not working. Can anyone please suggest how to write this custom rule correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"?  Is your rule throwing an exception, or does it have an unexpected behavior, or ???

Comment: @NicoleCalinoiu: It is not giving me the expected result.

Comment: What differs between your expected result and the actual result?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know with FxCop, but with NDepend (a .NET tool integrated in VS, that let's write custom code rules as C# LINQ queries) you just have to write:

```
// <Name>Namespace should start with XYZ</Name>
warnif count > 0 
from n in Application.Namespaces
where !n.Name.StartsWith("XYZ")
select n
```

The rule can be:

- [edited/compiled/executed live in VS](http://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL),
- can be saved and [checked regularly in VS](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/validating-cqlinq-code-rules-in-visual-studio)
- and at build-process time a [report can be built to show eventual rules violations](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/customize-ndepend-report#CQLRule)

[image: NDepend custom code rule Namespace should start with]

*Disclaimer: I work at NDepend*